# VSCode+java＋Springboot環境でクラスファイルを追加する

Tags: java, vscode, spring-boot

以下のページを参考に VSCode+java＋Springboot の環境を作りました。

[VSCodeでSpringBootのプロジェクト作成からアプリケーションの実行まで - Qiita](https://qiita.com/yama9112/items/ff829561238440437b99)

無事にアプリケーションは作成されたのですが、VSCodeでクラスファイル（たとえばcontrollerクラス）を追加する場合は、デフォルトで以下のような内容が追加されたりはできないのでしょうか？（Eclipseを使用していた感じにはならないのでしょうか？）

```
package com.example.sampleproject.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class SampleController {

}
```

Comment: 新規ファイル作成時に「テンプレートを自動で挿入したい」ということでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私は利用したことがないのですが、[Spring Roo](https://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/)のEclipse/STS pluginのことでしょうか。
(検索してみたところ、昔のSTSではインストール時に選択できていた用に見受けられます([参考](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1110/05/news123.html)))

こちらは一時期流行ったscaffolding機能を提供するものですが、元々はCLIツールであり[コマンドラインで実行できます](https://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/#spring-mvc-contollers)。
VSCode用のextensionは提供されていないようです。

また、[開発は停滞しているように見えます](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo)。
少なくとも、現在の[STS4](https://spring.io/tools)では、EclipseベースのものであってもSpring Rooへの導線はありません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。勘違いしていました。「CLIツールでありコマンドラインで実行できます。」コマンドラインで追加していた…ような覚えがありました。STSが重く、最近VSCodeをよく使うので開発環境をVSCodeで用意したいなと思っていたのですが、クラスファイルを追加するときVSCodeの場合、皆さんはどうしているんだろうという…という謎から始まった質問でした。VSCodeの拡張機能はないのですね。残念。CLIで追加できないものかも試してみたいと思います。勉強になりました。